# Вызвать функцию в функции

Tags: javascript

Есть такая структура (которую желательно бы не менять кардинально):

```
var wrapper1 = function ()
{
    var wrapper2 = function ()
    {
        return Math.PI;
    };
};
```

Пробовал через `var caller = new wrapper1;` вызвать так `caller.wrapper2()`, но возвращает undefined.
Подскажите как быть, пожалуйста. Не получается никак понять ооп в js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `var wrapper2 = ...` на `this.wrapper2 = ...`.
Когда вы пишете **var** внутри функции, то эта переменная (которая ссылается на функцию) видна только внутри функции. Если же вы обращаетесь к **this** (в случае javascript при создании нового экземпляра объекта через `new somefunction()` **this** внутри этой самой функции-конструктора указывает на созданный объект.
Тогда через `this.wrapper2 = ...` вы создаете новое поле в объекте и кладете в него свою функцию.

Comment: Нельзя так, тогда если будет [такая](http://joxi.ru/nAy6BDnhYjljzr)  стурктура, то всё рухнет. Так не получится...

Comment: @VostokSisters у вас переменная wrapper3 получает значение, возвращенное функцией wrapper2, а не this.wrapper2. замените **wrapper2()** на **this.wrapper2()** в теле последней анонимной функции

Comment: В принципе, [работает.](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/02/01/0001/0403/94611/11/26a2792e6a.png). Но при "use strict" - нет... Это нормально?

Comment: Вот [доказательство](http://joxi.ru/Vrwe3DVSO8R4Y2).

Comment: А куда таким образом ссылается `this`? На объект `caller` или на саму функцию `wrapper1`?

Comment: @VostokSisters на объект caller, хоть это и не совсем верная формулировка) да, при использовании функции как конструктор this внутри ссылается на новый экземпляр, т.е. новый объект

Comment: @VostokSisters, `wrapper3` использует функцию IIFE, а в функциях `this` указывает на `window` (`undefined`, если `"use strict";`). Я упустил этот факт, поэтому правильнее так: `let wrapper3 = (_ => this.wrapper2())()`.

Comment: @Other, а почему указывает на window, а не на объект `caller`? `wrapper3` ведь не использует функцию IIFE, он сам такая функция.

Comment: В функциях так устроено - сброс `this`. Частично из-за этого ввели стрелки. Вы присваиваете значение для `wrapper3` как раз из IIFE, если не сделать её стрелкой, то внутри контекст будет потерян.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, ведь `wrapper2` - приватная переменная; она существует только во время выполнения функции (или в замыкании, чего тут нет).
Используйте `this`:

```js
var wrapper1 = function ()
{
    this.wrapper2 = function ()
    {
        return Math.PI;
    };
}

var caller = new wrapper1;
console.info(caller.wrapper2());
```

Comment: Нельзя так, тогда если будет [такая](http://joxi.ru/nAy6BDnhYjljzr)  стурктура, то всё рухнет. Так не получится...

Comment: Другими словами, `wrapper2()` должна быть видна в скопе wrapper1.

Comment: @VostokSisters, а кто Вам мешает вызвать так: `return this.wrapper2();`?

Comment: Да никто, но тогда не работает при "use strict"...

Comment: Если "use strict" объявить в `wrapper1`.

Comment: @Other не так хорошо знаком с js, могу ошибаться, но скорее всего в строгом режиме this в последней анонимной функции уже не указывает на созданный объект, т.к. находится в этой самой анонимной функции. Да, это вполне нормально.

Comment: @Alexander, а-а-а, может быть. Я вроде на такое натыкался...

Comment: @Alexander, да, если объявить глобально, то всё будет хорошо.

Comment: @Alexander, если строгий режим, то стрелки помогут.

Comment: @Other ну то ведь только для es6, не стоит автору их пока использовать.

Comment: @Alexander, что Вы, они уже давно поддерживаются всеми нормальными браузерами. А для остальных есть MasterCard, т. е. Babel.

Comment: @Other да, я понимаю, однако для начала (тк автор изучает функции-конструкторы), не стоит  использовать стрелки, дабы разобраться в основах

Comment: @Alexander, а разве это не основы? Не нужно учить старое, т. к. оно было раньше, нужно учить что есть.

Comment: `function` всё ещё основы. Кроме того лексический this нужен не всегда (прим: в обработчиках событй в jquery, порой, удобней использовать, тот что подставляет jquery).

Comment: А стрелка легко заменяется на `function(){}.bind( this );`

Comment: @Arnial, а стрелки - близнец основ с особенностями. И у стрелок не только `this` отсутствует, так что Ваш пример не полон.